# Hyperlink to a specific text in a webpage

Tags: hyperlink, webpage

I'm looking for a way to get the hyperlink to a specific locution in a webpage. E.g. in [this](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/terminate-c-thread/) webpage I'd like to get the hyperlink such that clicking on it, the paragraph "C Thread Termination Example" opens.

Could you tell me which options I have please?

---

EDIT: the icon of the extension "link to text fragment" is always grey, I can't go to its options, and, if I right click on a locution, the option "Copy Link to Selected Text" doesn't appear.

[image]

Comment: The extension is normally grey on the toolbar, but it should be colored when you right click. It is no longer grey on the toolbar when you have copied a text on a website .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently Google added this feature in Chrome. The steps are:

1. select the text;
2. right click on it;
3. select Copy link to highlight.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Chrome (or Edge) as your browser, you could try [Link to text Fragment](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-to-text-fragment/pbcodcjpfjdpcineamnnmbkkmkdpajjg?hl=en). It's a:

> Browser extension that allows for linking to arbitrary text on a page.
>
> This extension allows for easily creating a special link to the currently selected text on a page via the context menu. When opening such a special link, a compatible browser will scroll the selected text into view and highlight it.

Here is the [link](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/terminate-c-thread/#more-10260:%7E:text=C%20Thread%20Example%20Program,the%20process%20terminated%20as%20main()%20returned.) to "C Thread Termination Example". I highlighted the whole paragraph, but I could have just highlighted the its title. Another [link](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/terminate-c-thread/#more-10260:%7E:text=Thread%20Termination,then%20there%20is%20a%20function%20pthread_join().) from the same page.

Here are the instructions on how to use it:

> - Select the text that you want to link to.
> - Right-click and choose "Copy Link to Selected Text" from the context menu.
> - If the link creation succeeded, the selected text will be briefly highlighted in yellow.
> - Paste your link wherever you want to share it.
> - Pro-tip: use a keyboard shortcut (by default: Command+Shift+L or Ctrl+Shift+L).

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

**Note:** I have tested with more browsers, at times after clicking the links the paragrah that should be highlighted is not shown. Pressing Enter on the address bar, then shows it.

**Disclaimer:** I am just a user of the extension.

Comment: Hello @ReddyLutonadio thank you for your reply. I have that extension, but it doesn't work: the option "Copy Link to Selected Text"  doesn't appear. Morover, if  I click on the link you posted, the webpage starts from the beginning

Comment: What about this [link](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/terminate-c-thread/#more-10260:~:text=Thread%20Termination,then%20there%20is%20a%20function%20pthread_join().) ?

Comment: the same as before:(

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi i have added gifs to show what I see when I click on the links. What browser are you using and its version? Maybe try to close and restart it.

Comment: I tried to do it, but nothing....I'm using: google chrome Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi That's also the version of Chrome I have. If you have Edge (the latest), Opera or any other browser of the Chromium family, re the links also not shown properly

Comment: it works in opera. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi See edit about the Note. Check if Chrome is behaving that way on your side.

Comment: it's very very weird, after the opera installation, the extension works in chrome as well (now the icon is colored)